# How to create a default constraint in EF code-first and Azure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have the following code-first Entity Framework code that I'm using with Azure Mobile services:

```
public class BookContext : DbContext
{
private const string connectionStringName = "Name=MS_TableConnectionString";

public BookContext() : base(connectionStringName) { } 

// The collections queried directly.
public DbSet<Book> Books{ get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Standard code to add the "service" columns such as CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, and Deleted.
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
        new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
            "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));

    // Add a default value 0 on the Deleted column. The following code does not work.
    modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
                .Property(p => p.Deleted)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
}
}
```

As noted above, the code is supposed to add a default constraint on the Deleted column, but it does not do anything. I'd like to achieve an equivalent of the following SQL statement as the EF code-first:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Books ADD CONSTRAINT DF_BooksDeleted DEFAULT 0 FOR Deleted
```

Apparently, I must be doing something wrong. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, default values for database is part of EF Core, for more details, you could refer to [Default Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values).

Based on your requirement, you are trying to set default value for the system column `Deleted` of Azure Mobile service tables. I assumed that you could override [EntityTableSqlGenerator.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/04d75cadc137cc478f98edfa1fa5b868e5548dfd/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Entity/Tables/EntityTableSqlGenerator.cs) and add the logic for setting default value for system column `Deleted` and your custom columns as follows:

**MyEntityTableSqlGenerator.cs**

```
public class MyEntityTableSqlGenerator : EntityTableSqlGenerator
{
    protected override void UpdateTableColumn(ColumnModel columnModel, TableColumnType tableColumnType)
    {
        //for system column deleted
        switch (tableColumnType)
        {
            case TableColumnType.Deleted:
                columnModel.DefaultValue = 0;
                break;
        }
        base.UpdateTableColumn(columnModel, tableColumnType);
    }

    protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
    {
        //for your custom columns
        foreach (ColumnModel column in createTableOperation.Columns)
        {
            TableColumnType tableColumnType = this.GetTableColumnType(column);
            if (tableColumnType == TableColumnType.None)
            {
                if (column.Annotations.Keys.Contains("DefaultValue"))
                {
                    var value = Convert.ChangeType(column.Annotations["DefaultValue"].NewValue, column.ClrDefaultValue.GetType());
                    column.DefaultValue = value;
                }
            }
        }

        //for system columns
        base.Generate(createTableOperation);
    }
}
```

**Modify `Configuration.cs` and add your custom SqlGenerator:**

```
public Configuration()
{
    SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new MyEntityTableSqlGenerator());
}
```

Then, modify your `OnModelCreating` method as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{   
    //set default value for your custom columns
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
        .Property(p => p.Status)
        .HasColumnName("Status")
        .HasColumnAnnotation("DefaultValue","false");

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
        new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
            "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));

}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bruce. Your code is working great. In fact, I needed only add the EntityTableSqlGenerator and leave OnModelCreating as is. The default constraint on the Deleted column was created anyway. Why would I need to set default value for the Deleted column in OnModelCreating?

Comment: I thought the `Deleted` column has no default constraint, thanks for reminding me.  For set default value for your custom columns, you could refer to the rest part.

Comment: Let me clarify: The purpose of MyEntityTableSqlGenerator is to set the value of the Default constraint. The purpose of OnModelCreating is to create the Default constraint. Is it correct? If so, I have probably already run OnModelCreating which created the Default constraint.